# Python returns None at closure while using decorators

Tags: python-decorators, python-3.7

The Problem is that the inner function returns None instead of resulting the output if the second digit is not zero!

Why does it not act as a normal decorator?

**Code:**

```
def check(fun):
    def inner_fun(a,b):
        if b == 0:
            print("0 is not valid")
            return
        fun(a,b)
    return inner_fun  #returns None

def divide(a,b):
    return a / b

divide = check(divide)

print(divide(5, 0))
```

> **Output:**
>   `0 is not valid`
>   `None`

Comment: You should return your wrapped function call in the decorator i.e. `return fun(a,b)` to get what you want

Answer (score 0):

The inner function does not return the value you expect because... it does not `return`.  Instead,  it implicitly returns None, as Python functions do when they reach the end of control flow.

You can edit the inner function to return `f(a, b)` in the normal case:

```
def check(fun):
   def inner_fun(a,b):
        if b == 0:
            print("0 is not valid")
            return       # implicitly returns None
        return fun(a,b)  # note return
    return inner_fun
```

Comment: it also return None at when the if statement is not executed

Comment: That’s because in the original, `inner_func` computes `f(a, b)` in that case, *but does not return* the computed value.

Comment: Great!  If this answered your question, please see this help center topic:  [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)